# Monitoring activities of the VPS in real time?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, monitoring, vps, teamviewer

I want to monitor someone's activities when he logs in to my VPS. It's Windows VPS. You know, when you remote the VPS you need to login to the Windows user account and one account doesn't accept 2 logins.

I've tried to use teamviewer, but it only works when I connected to the VPS already, otherwise Teamviewer always tell me the password to connect is invalid ! I think Teamviewer uses the same remote connection as Windows does.

So, I wonder if there is another software to monitor activities of the VPS in real time, like teamviewer.

Or I have another idea :  we can not connect simultaneously to a same Windows user account but we can connect to 2 different accounts at the same time. So if there is a software can monitor another user account in the same Windows, it also solves this case !

For example : The Windows of the VPS has 2 accounts : account A and account B. Then someone is remoting the account A and I am remoting the account B. If account B can monitor the account A then it means I can monitor the account A.

Sorry for my English, hope you can understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is built into Windows. If you have sufficient privileges, you can control another Terminal Services session using the **`shadow`** command (get session ID from `qwinsta`), or the "Remote Control" menu option in Task Manager. By default, though, Windows will ask the other user for confirmation; this can be changed in `lusrmgr.msc`.

Comment: Sorry I can't get you. More details please ?

Comment: @ITFan: Task Manager -> "Users" tab -> right-click -> "Remote Control"

Comment: It has error : http://i.imgur.com/m2HEG.png

Comment: By the way, is your solution for making multiple logon to a same Windows User account or else ?